# How do I initialise a struct that contains a reference?

Tags: initialization, rust, lifetime

I want to write an initialiser for the following struct.

```
struct Foo {
    bar: &Bar
}
```

It's recommended to use `&T` over `Box<T>` for flexibility and that's what I'm going for here. Without an initialiser you'd use the struct like this.

```
{
    let bar = ...;
    let foo = Foo { bar: bar };

    // use foo    

    // dealloc bar and foo
}
```

This works. But I want to allocate `&Bar` in the initialiser. Now obviously allocating `bar` on the stack will not work because it goes out of scope once the initialiser returns. So I thought I could use `Box`.

```
fn new() -> Foo {
    let bar = Box::new(...);
    Foo { bar: &*bar }
}
```

This does not work either because I guess we're just borrowing the value instead of transferring ownership which will still deallocate `bar` once `new` returns.

Am I forced to use a `Box` in the struct in this case?

#### EDIT

*Note*: The reason the reference is needed is because `Bar` is actually a generic trait in my case and thus the size can vary which means allocation on the stack won't work.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2vynfa/stackoverflow_resources_in_initialisers_help_is/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say for sure without knowing what `Bar` is. If it's a trait, then yeah it needs to be a `&Bar` or `Box<Bar>`. If it's just a regular type, then the normal thing to do is to store it directly:

```
struct Foo {
    bar: Bar
}
```

When you hear that `&Bar` is preferred for flexibility, that's usually with respect to function parameters, e.g. `fn func(bar: &Bar)`, and even then it really depends on what you're actually doing. However, when defining a field on a struct, storing the value directly is usually what you want, unless you know what you're doing. This conveys clearly that the `Foo` *owns* the `Bar`.

Comment: Yes, it is a trait and actually generic and thus the size can vary, which is why the reference is needed in the first place. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah in that case, AFAIK, you have to provide a reference that outlives the initializer, so it would have to be passed into the initializer as an argument. Otherwise yeah you'd have to use a Box, since in that case the lifetime wouldn't factor in because you'd be moving it entirely into the new struct.

Answer (score 7):

Your question doesn't really make sense. If you are constructing the object in your `new` method, then by definition *you know what the type is* (because you are calling that constructor), and you don't need to treat it as a trait object. You should just use the type!

> The reason the reference is needed is because Bar is actually a generic trait in my case and thus the size can vary which means allocation on the stack won't work.

This isn't completely true! If you wanted to accept a parameter, and you want to transfer ownership, then you can simply restrict the type to the trait you wish:

```
trait Talker { fn talk(&self); }

struct Dog;
impl Talker for Dog { fn talk(&self) { println!("Woof") }}

struct Cat;
impl Talker for Cat { fn talk(&self) { println!("Meow") }}

struct OwnAGeneric<T: Talker> {
    t: T
}

impl<T: Talker> OwnAGeneric<T> {
    fn new(t: T) -> OwnAGeneric<T> { OwnAGeneric { t: t } }

    fn talk(&self) { println!("I own this:"); self.t.talk(); }
}

fn main() {
    let owned_cat = OwnAGeneric::new(Cat);  
    owned_cat.talk();
}
```

This should be monomorphized by the compiler and basically as fast as if you had written the code out by hand. This also allows everything to be allocated on the stack.